# Stop/Avoid overlapping desktop icons?

Tags: icons, bug-reporting, desktop-icons

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Icons on Desktop overlaps as follows:

[image: screen]

I want to avoid this and set icons' possible positions only on finite grid alignment.

How to do/solve this?

Comment: I choses command (gsettings etc.) rater-than GUI-tweak if possible.

Comment: "Keep Aligned" & "Organize by Desktop by Name" options are not remembers setting permanently and I have to use **every time**.

Comment: It remembers Keep Aligned option for me but it looks like there are several grids at the same time with different spacing and it is actually nearly impossible to align icons by hand when this option is checked ...

Comment: Any sollution for this ?

Comment: @Kuba now i am not using unity

Comment: Looks like this can't be configured from Nautilus (the default filemanager/desktop for Ubuntu) itself.

Comment: I had the same problem. Apparently, it is a conflict with nemo. So, in my case it was solved by purging nemo package.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `iconic` to solve this problem by letting you define a grid size larger than the icons. Additionally it will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.